# How to calculate the difference between two datetimes using PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

I have two dates of the form:

```
Start Date: 2012-02-10 11:26:00
End Date: 2012-04-25 01:50:00
```

Now I need to find the difference between these two in the below form:

```
 years,  months, days, hours, minutes, seconds
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Didn't get correct answer. Thats y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$start_date = new DateTime("2012-02-10 11:26:00");
$end_date = new DateTime("2012-04-25 01:50:00");
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
echo "Result " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```